# How to show images on text hover in google docs addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I am new to google docs Add-ons. I am working on an add-on in which I need to show set of image on text hover like tooltip in html

I did not find a way to implement this after hours of googling. please help.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The above because the Documents Service of Google Apps Script doesn't include "on hover" event / trigger or something similar

The only way is by using a dialog or sidebar and they can only be launched by clicking on a custom menu or by using `google.script.run` on a previously opened dialog / sidebar.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/doc
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Related

- [Show Popup of YouTube video within Google Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49792917/1595451)