# Show Popup of YouTube video within Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to show YouTube video as pop over on Google Doc.
So, if I keep a YouTube link within my Google Doc and then click on the link then the YouTube video should show / play as pop up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the [help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for query and answer under this tag, [google-apps-script]. I did not found any useful information. That is why I asked it.

Comment: You can build the dialog in script editor by selecting html script and using standard html. Use the embed code from YouTube. In DocumentApp there are a couple of show dialog methods. Check [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Comment: Thanks. The YouTube link will be on the doc.
Once user will click the link then the YouTube video need to show as pop. but dialog is preset. I need to catch that user has been clicked on YouTube link and make sure the video will play on pop.

Comment: Google Docs Help Forum saying that it's impossible. But I believe, 
"Nothing is impossible".
See the Thread here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9wODGmbGp00

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use Apps Script to create a custom dialog with the YouTube video in it, you can't initiate Apps Script from a link in a Google Doc. You'd have to add a menu item to the doc which would look for all the YouTube links in the doc and give the user the ability to select which one to play.

Comment: Thanks.
What I'm looking for is, The YouTube link will be on the doc. Once user will click the link then the YouTube video need to show as pop. but dialog is preset. I need to catch that user has been clicked on YouTube link and make sure the video will play on pop.
So I am thinning the process like this:

1. Search within the Active Docs for YouTube link. 
2. Then write event on onClick
3.  Within the Google App Script there are dialog, show the YouTube video within the Dialog as pop or iFrame

Please let me know  your thoughts.